# moving java class bytecode from jvm to jvm

Tags: java

So i have a server jvm and a client jvm. The client communicates with the server by sending serialized java objects over tcp. Now, normally the server would have the classes of the objects it was receiving in its classpath, in order to deserialize the objects properly.

But what i'm looking for is some way to avoid that; ie, have the client "somehow" send the class bytecode over the wire, on-demand. This would of course require recursing down the class tree (in case any members of the original class where themselves objects of other classes that the server didn't know about).

So i was wondering about any technologies out there that do this sort of thing.

Thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[RMI has the ability to dynamically download entire class file definitions over the wire on demand](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/codebase.html).

Even if you don't use (or want to use) RMI, the technologies underlying the classloading may be of interest, and they're standard Java.

Comment: Yes, we already have a framework for doing "rmi"; so looking at the underlying technologies would be of interest.

Answer (score 4):

RMI includes the notion of a "class server." Sounds like you're pretty much reinventing that, so consider looking into using all or part of RMI. [Here's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/index.html) a tutorial.

Comment: RMI does this by default, but I'd suggest deploying the class files to where they are needed rather than going for something a bit clever.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking about [Code Mobility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_mobility). Also the area of grid computing is somewhat relevant.

Take a look at [Mobility-RPC](http://code.google.com/p/mobility-rpc/), it's a library which does exactly what you ask at the same level of granularity (class-level).

Security is something to bear in mind. But I'd also remember that SQL sent to databases, bash commands executed over SSH, Business rules engines, Adobe Flash, Java Applets, RMI as described above, ActiveX, JavaScript, Hadoop/grid computing frameworks - all of these are examples of remote code execution in widespread use. Like everything, turning the security dial to the max is going to limit your options. But all of the above are used to good effect when properly firewalled or sandboxed.

In this instance, it sounds like you want something to eliminate a minor hassle, and you're not (say) designing a full-blown distributed application. So based on what you've said, despite myself being somewhat of a code mobility proponent, I'd say code mobility is probably overkill in this case. (But useful in others.)

Regarding grid computing, take a look at [GridGain](http://www.gridgain.com/), and [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/). GridGain is a pure (CPU-centric) grid computing framework, whereas Hadoop is more a data mining/data warehouse platform with its own replicated distributed file system (HDFS).

Both GridGain and Hadoop transmit user-defined Java code implementing tasks/jobs to remote worker nodes. Last time I checked, they did this by transferring user-supplied jar files to the relevant nodes. I think the GridGain ClassLoader is more sophisticated than Hadoop's however (but less sophisticated than Mobility-RPC's). Hadoop basically starts a new JVM for every job, not especially efficient (but not exactly the bottleneck given the IO load!).

Mobility-RPC is somewhat different because it doesn't expect the remote machine to be a worker node at all, it could be any application running the library. So it's more like RPC or ad-hoc task/object transfer.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a very bad idea. Basically, it would mean you allow your client to send code to the server which is directly executed inside the current process. Something like this is generally considered a serious vulnerability, namely [Arbitrary code execution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary_code_execution) which is one of the worst vulnerabilities you could ever have.

Building a system design based on that is well, not so smart.

Answer (score 0):

Create a classloader that loads classes from a stream. See the [JarFileClassLoader example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/jarclassloader.html) for details.

This, of course, will become hugely problematic, particularly if any of the classes use reflection and don't directly name an implementation in the bytecode, in addition to potential security issues; you'll need to look into secure classloaders.

Answer (score 0):

If plain RMI does not work for your requirements take a look to mobile agents frameworks in Java (e.g., Aglets).